Blazor/MAUI Hybrid with asp.net core backend Authorization and Authentication. Best way?
I have:

asp.net core for backend which has access to db and other stuff
Blazor wasm spa for website
MAUI Balzor Hybrid for mobile app
Razor RLC that is shared between the app and website
Using new Identity endpoints on backend (also ef, custom AuthenticationStateProvider, etc.)

The idea is that I make a website and app from the same code. As in not having to write app and website seperately with one backend that work for both of them.
That worked good so far, but I'm stuck and confused in regards to authorization and authentication and how to implement it so that they both use the same backend and that they both can use external logins as well, such as Google, Apple, etc. I also want that user can stay logged in for longer periods, basically until they decide to log out. What would be the ideal way to go about this? And preferably to use Microsoft Identity features, I'm not really a security expert so I don't want to experiment with my own implementations..
For Blazor Wasm (website) I can just do Identity cookies and that would probably work, but then apps can't have cookies, so I would have to go with bearer tokens, but then blazor supposedly can't securely store tokens if it's not on server side, so where would I store them? I also had troubles adding services on backend for both cookies and bearer tokens. Or would Blazor Identity cookies just work on Blazor/MAUI Hybrid, since its all wrapped into webview? Microsoft in their guides often want you to make use of 3rd party identity providers which I very much do not want.
So I have already lost a lot of time on that and I'm unsure what to explore next and am afraid of losing even more time by going into wrong direction. There is a lot of info on the web, but alot of it is not for my case and a lot of it is outdated, it's just one big mess as far as I'm concerned. And I didn't even start looking into external login..
Can someone help? Am I missing something obvious?

Why not Use Azure Active Directory B2C?

It feels like opening another can of worms and I'm not gonna know if its good and works for me unless I invest a good chunk of time trying to implement it, besides I would rather not pay the extra cost if I don't have too and have more freedom.
Do you have experience implementing it? Have you done so for your own stuff? What were the pros? what were the cons? How much freedom does it allow? Can I still have the users in sql database?
At the minimum I need to access the id or email of user to tie it with other sql databases I have.

I've used it.  If you want integration with external authentication providers such as Google, Facebook, Apple you are going to be writing a lot of code if you want to role your own.  You get an Id which you can match into "users" in standard SQL apps.  Check the pricing.  I use the basic implementation and it comes free with my account.  You need to "invest a good chunk of time" in testing any implementation to see if it's fit for purpose.  Implementing any complex system is a can of worms: that's the nature of Authentication/Authorization.  BTW - this is not a recommendation..

Hmm. Thanks. Well ofc time and complexity can vary. I guess what I meant with can of worms is that it's a whole other thing that I'll have to get to know with potential new problems or limitations, I would much rather finish of the thing I have now than throw it all away and start with a new thing. I mean at some point I will, but not yet :)
So it's not a recommendation, why not? Did you encounter any problems, annoyances, limitations or challenges implementing it?

I avoid recommendations: I have no idea about your context.  I don't know if it's the right solution for you.  Recommendations carry ownership.:  suddenly your problem becomes mine.  Happy coding.

I'm creating something pretty identical to what you're doing and so far auth has been my biggest challenge. I have a separate project with all my identity management components which is only used in my web app. The mobile app is using WebAuthenticator to go to my web login page. The web side does use HttpContext and cookies, the Maui side uses JWT bearer token. It works ok but I'm running into some strange quirks here and there which is why I'm still researching this topic. It's been a frustrating experience to say the least.
